# how to use Object.entries inside return function - reactjs

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is my object:

```
days:{
        "day":"0",
        "1":"01",
        "2":"02",
        "3":"03",
        "4":"04",
        "5":"05",
        "6":"06",
        "7":"07",
        "8":"08",
        "9":"09",
        "10":"10",
        "11":"11",
        "12":"12",
        "13":"13",
        "14":"14",
        "15":"15",
        "16":"16",
        "17":"17",
        "18":"18",
        "19":"19",
        "20":"20",
        "21":"21",
        "22":"22",
        "23":"23",
        "24":"24",
        "25":"25",
        "26":"26",
        "27":"27",
        "28":"28",
        "29":"29",
        "30":"30",
        "31":"31",
       }
```

but it doesn't return anything(it shows empty picker):

```
return (
            <Picker style={{width:'30%'}}>

            {Object.entries(days).forEach(([label, value]) => {
               return <Picker.Item label={label} value={value} /> 
            })}

            </Picker>
)
```

Comment: You can't return from `Array.forEach()`. Use `Array.map()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The map function returns an array of items and forEach just loop over them.